# transpose and filter multiple columns into single vector

Tags: r

I have CSVs in a clunky format (National Weather Service 'DATACARD' format - sample monthly data on page 3 [here](http://www.nws.noaa.gov/oh/hrl/nwsrfs/users_manual/part7/_pdf/72datacard.pdf)) and I'm hoping to find a better way of transposing and filtering out NAs. I think there may be something along the lines of `gather()` from the `tidyverse`, but I'm open to all approaches.

```
a <- c(10.5,14,16,20,23)
b <- c(11,15,17,21,24)
c <- c(12,NA,18,22,25.2)
d <- c(13,NA,19,NA,26)

rawcsv  <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
rawcsv_singlecolumn <- data.frame(singlecolumn=c(t(rawcsv)))
rawcsv_NAsremoved_thedesiredvector <- na.omit(rawcsv_singlecolumn)

desiredvector <-  c(10.5,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25.2,26)
```

Comment: do you need `na.omit(unlist(rawcsv))` ?

Comment: @Ronak, I think that's missing the transpose part, ie it gives me `[10.5, 14, 16, ...]`

Comment: yes, if the order of the numbers is important to you then we need to transpose it first. `unlist` splits it column-wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can extract the single column from the dataset

```
rawcsv_NAsremoved_thedesiredvector[[1]]
```

---

If we need to use `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
rownames_to_column(rawcsv, 'rn') %>% 
    gather(key, value, -rn, na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
    arrange(as.integer(rn)) %>% 
    pull(value)
```

Comment: If I weren't to use `tidyverse`, what could I apply starting with `rawcsv`? thank you.

Comment: @doconnor In that case, the most obvious way would be `c(na.omit(c(t(rawcsv))))` i.e. you don't need to create a `data.frame` again, instead the matrix (`t`- transpose of data.frame) can be stripped of its `dim` attributes with `c` (to convert to `vector`), apply the `na.omit` to remove the `NA` elements and remove the attributes created by `na.omit` with `c`